# Simple Importing in functional (non-class-oriented) files

Tags: php

Sorry, I'm new to php and newer to testing.

I've got my code file set up with a bunch of declarative functions (i.e., not as a class).

#### `./src/code.php`

```php
function doThis() { return "this is done"; }
function doThat() { return "that is done"; }
```

And I've got my Kahlan spec file to test the code, in

#### `./spec/code.spec.php`

```php
describe("doThis", function() {
  it("does this", function() {
    expect(doThis())->toEqual("this is done");
  });
});
```

But the test file can't find the code, of course:

```php
message:`Error` Code(0) with message "Call to undefined function doThis()"
```

I've tried some `@include` (which has worked in the rest of this PHP plugin) and I've tried some `Namespace` but I don't know what I'm doing. I prefer human answers to the understandable RTFM. Anyone care to offer some simple direct help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the basic question, I'll do my penance by posting the basic answer.

Adding this to my test file gets in what I need:

```php
$dir = dirname(__FILE__);

@include_once "$dir/../controllers/subscription_products_controller.php";
```

Since my file structure is

```
|--controllers
|   └--subscription_products_controller.php
|
└--spec
    └--collate.spec.php
```